# Trying to locate the div after a particular h2 using Selenium locator

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, instagram

**Task**: To identify the date and time of each post that references a particular hashtag in Instagram ([e.g.](https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/bestday/)).

**Method**: Search for the first post after "Most Recent" heading and click on it, then click the right arrow to continue moving through the posts.

**Problem**: I am having difficulty identifying the first post after the heading "Most Recent".

**Code**:

```
most_recent = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//h2[contains(text(), 'Most Recent')]")
ele_post = most_recent.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.v1Nh3 a') 
ele_post.click()
```

**Output**: 
The above ultimately returns the date and time of the first post in "Top Posts" *not* "Most Recent".

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. (Stupidly not locating the element inside which the div I'm searching for is located.)

This code works:

```
most_recent = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//span[normalize-space(text()) = \'Most Recent\']/following::h2)[1]")
ele_post = most_recent.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.v1Nh3 a') 
ele_post.click()
```